# Similarity search in a python database using rdkit

Tags: python, postgresql, similarity, rdkit, cheminformatics

How to run a similarity search in a database and the output should be a table with molecules which passed a specific treshold?

I tried this

```
query = sql.SQL("""
        SELECT *, morganbv_fp(smiles::qmol) %% morganbv_fp(%s::qmol) AS similarity
        FROM {}
        WHERE morganbv_fp(smiles::qmol) %% morganbv_fp(%s::qmol) > %s
        ORDER BY similarity DESC
```

Comment: And, what happened?